# Resolving the variables in options nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Hi i make a client call to a hhtp get webservice using the http module

I pass options as a input to the function.Below is the code snippet

```
var headerKey="ddd"
options = {
             host: 10.0.0.0,
             port: 80,
             path:/pppp,
             headers: {
                 headerKey : 1
          }
        };
```

When i print options below is the output

```
options:-{"host":"10.0.0.0","port":80,"path":"/pppp","headers":{"headerKey":"1"}}
```

My issue is that the "headerkey" is not changing to ddd instead its passing the variable name as the parameter.(ie) I want the out put as below

```
{"host":"10.0.0.0","port":80,"path":"/pppp","headers":{"ddd":"1"}}
```

I am stuck here.Any help regarding this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean changing `option`'s `headerKey` to `ddd`

```
var headerKey = 'ddd';
options = {...};
options.headers.headerKey = headerKey;
```

---

As far as I know, you can't rename a property in JS. You could add another property, and [have it point to the same value](http://jsfiddle.net/awjHc/1/) as the previous:

```
options.headers[headerKey] = options.headers.headerKey;
delete options.headers.headerKey;
```

Comment: The value is not changing its till passing as headerKey

Comment: @AmandaG can you post the code and the output? Because from your post, [it should be working as intended](http://jsfiddle.net/awjHc/). With the code above, the options should now be: `"headers":{"headerKey":"ddd"}`

Comment: I want the "headerKey"  to be changed not its value (ie) the output should be like "headers":{"ddd":"1"}

Comment: @AmandaG you should have said that in the post. But you said *"headerkey is not getting resolved to ddd"*

Comment: @ Joseph the Dreamer :Sorry I actually meant the key not changing,not its value

Answer (score 0):

[check out this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fhzXs/)

```
var headerKey="ddds"
 var options = {
         host: "10.0.0.0",
         port: "80",
         path:"/pppp",
headers: {}

};

options.headers[headerKey] = '1';

console.log(options);

console.log(options.headers);
```

To use a variable as a key in javascript you can use the [array notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html) of the objects.